# how to implement pull to refresh in android app

Tags: android, adt, pull-to-refresh

I have an app for getting the RSS feeds and I am trying to implement pull to refresh. I took reference from https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh. 
Can anyone help to include this in eclipse? Do we have jars for this?

Comment: what you have tried? any errors ?any exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjmdELnm3GI) video and [this](http://www.thoughtsonmobile.com/2012/09/android-pull-to-refresh.html) page (with code) to implement it since there is no direct controls for it yet in android

Some snippets :
In xml:

```
<!--
  The PullToRefresh-ListView replaces a standard ListView widget,
  and has all the features android.widget.ListView has.
-->
<eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

On Activity:

```
// Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
PullToRefreshListView pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);
pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
        // Do work to refresh the list here.
        new GetDataTask().execute();
    }
});

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        pullToRefreshView.onRefreshComplete();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: These links can rot, please expand on your answer

Comment: @Reno: Me too wanna explain more; But there is too much code to explain mate; Thats why I posted the link; will post the major parts now

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Get the new corrections at the link I said on top